# Spring Boot keeps crashing my pc...what is the best configuration for sts.ini file on Windows 10?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-tool-suite

I'm using Spring Tool Suite IDE on a Windows 10 laptop with an i5 core processor.  Every time I try to run a Spring Boot App, STS hangs and crashes.  The same app works fine on my peers' computers.

Now, even when I run a simple program to practice some coding challenges such as reversing a string, STS will slow down a bit and is not as smooth as before.

These are my current sts.ini file configurations:

```
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.1100.v20190907-0426
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.5.600.v20191014-2022.jar
-product
org.springframework.boot.ide.branding.sts4
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Xms256m
-Xmx1024m
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:+UseStringDeduplication
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
```

I was considering changing my Xmx and Xms size. What should I increase this to for better STS performance.

Comment: Did you try to force the jvm using `-vm` ? Use the latest version of sts 4.5.1 and a clean install of e.g. adoptopenjdk

Comment: This is hard to answer in general, would there are several steps that you could try to find out what exactly is causing the issue. First step would be to enable the head status in the general preferences to see if the IDE is indeed running out of memory. If not, you can take a look at the Error Log to see what might be going wrong and whether there is a memory problem being reported. I would still wonder why 1GB of max heap doesn't allow you to work on a simple example program, therefore the analysis steps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on your Random Access Memory (RAM) of system.

As per your current sts.ini file,

-Xms256m

-Xmx1024m

which is generally set for 2GB RAM of system.

If you have more than 2GB RAM, for example 4GB RAM, please set:

-Xms512m

-Xmx2048m

Above settings indicates STS will occupy upto 2GB of your 4GB RAM of system, among all other open applications .

Thanks and Regards.